# Secure deployments of on-prem artifacts to cloud

Tags: jenkins, deployment, artifacts, bamboo

Right now, we have locally hosted (across multiple Datacenters) artifactory and Bitbucket. We're at a halfway point between Jenkins and Bamboo (with Jenkins beginning to make more traction against Bamboo).

However, we're currently going through the task of building out a hybrid cloud platform, which is essentially going to be K8s on top of a cloud provider such as AWS or Azure. However, I've no idea how to approach ***securely*** deploying code or artifacts over the internet. Nor can I seem to find a 'best practice' cheat sheet.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Both Azure and AWS will have any container images built off their network pushed to their repositories using https which will encrypt the transfer (e.g. [AWS ECR encryption](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/features/)).  Both of these providers offer ways to encrypt the transfer of data into their non-container storage solutions (often via https) and then offer ways to encrypt the data at rest.  Once it is on the cloud provider deploying to k8s can all be done securely within their servers.